# On the embedding of a function space $X$ into $L^2\cap L^4$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

It is well-known that if $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain, then we have the embedding
$$
L^4({\Omega})\subset L^2({\Omega})
$$
since $||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C(\Omega) ||f||_{L^4(\Omega)}$ by Hölder's inequality. However, the above inequality no longer holds when $\Omega$ is unbounded.

Now, for general domain $\Omega$, let us consider the set $\mathcal{F}=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C||f||_{L^4(\Omega)}< \infty\}$,  and $C$ is an universal constant independent of $f$. I am wondering if there exists a function space $X$ such that $X\subset\mathcal{F}$, where $X$ contains functions with non-compact support. It is okay to assume $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Trivially, $X=0$, or $X = C^\infty_c(U)$ for some bounded set $U \subset \Omega$.  Maybe you should be more specific about what properties you want $X$ to have.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, $X=C_c^{\infty}$ serves as a good example. But in fact, I'm looking for a space $X$ that contains functions with non-compact supports.

Comment: Let $X$ be the one-dimensional space spanned by $f(x) = e^{-|x|^2}$, or your other favorite non-compactly-supported function $f \in L^2(\Omega) \cap L^4(\Omega)$?  (I pride myself on the ability to produce annoying trivial examples that fit requirements but are obviously not what people want... so keep trying :-)

Comment: Your construction are indeed quite helpful. Basically, we need functions that decays fast at infinity. Does Schwartz class $\mathcal{S}$ work?

Comment: Assuming you want your constant $C$ to be independent of $f$, then $\mathcal{S}$ will not work.  Since $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in both $L^2$ and $L^4$, you will be able to find functions in $\mathcal{S}$ with $L^2$ norm very large and $L^4$ norm very small.  $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ will not work for the same reason.

Comment: Why necessary bounded? Finite measure is enough.

Comment: The definition of the class $\mathcal F $ is not completely clear to me: (1) is $\|f\|_{L^4(\Omega)}$ assumed to be finite? (2) Does $C$ depend on $f$?

Comment: @PietroMajer Good point, I do require the norm $||f||_{L^4(\Omega)}$ to be finite and $C$ is universal constant, independent of $f$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I believe that at this point, the space spanned by $e^{-|x|^2}$ is good enough. What I'm trying to work out is a PDE problem, the function $f$ serves as part of my initial data, which can be naturally assumed to have fast decay. Above this, $|x|^a e^{-ax}$ should also work, for $a>0$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov  Unfortunately finite measure is not enough for my current project, as I'm working on a PDE problem in $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, in my last result, I assumed Ω is bounded, and now I want to drop the assumption.

Comment: Adding the requirement that $\|f\|_4$ be bounded by a universal constant $M$ changed the problem substantially.  Now $\mathcal{F}$ cannot be a vector space.

Comment: If $X\subset\mathcal F$ cannot be a vector space, what could it be that make sense? A ball in a normed space? The underlying question may be: somehow I got an estimate $||f||_{L^4(\mathbb R^n}\le M$, what else should I know to be able to bound $||f||_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}$ ?

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point. I have refined my argument and now we only require that $||f||_{L^4}$ is finite, but the constant $C$ has to be universal

Comment: @JeanDuchon Yes, this is exactly I'm looking for at this point, we know at this point (due to Nate Elderdge) that $f$ has to decay fast at infinty, which is a standard assumption in PDE theory for long time well-posedness

Comment: A few comments: (1) The formulation by Jean Duchon is much better then what you have written above, at least the intent is much more clear. (2) The connection with $\Omega$ being bounded is perhaps much more directly seen to be that of $$ \|gw\|_{L^2} \leq \|g\|_{L^4} \|w\|_{L^4} $$ which holds for any domain. In your case you let $w \equiv 1$ when $\Omega$ is bounded. For the unbounded case you are looking for $f = gw$ so you want $w$ to be a non-vanishing weight on $\Omega$ that is $L^4$. And then $\|f\|_{L^2}$ can be bounded by $f$ in some weighted $L^4$ norm. For PDE purposes straight-up..

Comment: .. decay rate assumptions are often way too restrictive; it is much better to use weighted norms instead (which is really just thinking of decay rates dually). So if you have the freedom, maybe instead of proving simply that $\|f\|_4$ is bounded, you should try to prove it for some weighted versions? Or you can ask yourself whether a weighted $L^2$ norm is good enough for your applications. Or you can just tell us what your application is, because as it stands the question is extremely vague and not really answerable.

Comment: (3) It would be much easier to say something if you tell us what other properties of $X$ you may want. For example: do you want $X$ to be a translation invariant vector space (meaning that if $f(x)\in X$ then $g(x) = f(x + v)$ for some $v$ is also $\in X$)? For PDEs this may be a desirable condition. But if so, you may have an obstruction from concentration compactness.

Comment: Observe that the constant $C$ in the desired inequality $||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C(\Omega) ||f||_{L^4(\Omega)}$ has dimension (length)$^{n/4}$. This suggests to look for a space ($X$) of functions whose Fourier transforms vanish for spatial frequencies $|\xi|\le\Xi$ for some $\Xi$ (of dimension (length)$^{-1}$) and try to get inequalities $||f||_{L^2}\leq c(n) \Xi^{-n/4}||f||_{L^4}$ for $f\in X$. That would probably not solve any PDE problem, but at least it would answer the question as stated... (if successful, of course).

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the comments, in fact I'm working on an apriori estimates problem on unbounded domain $\Omega$ (I've done the bounded case). In the unbounded case, I need to either include $||f||_{L^2}$ in my apriori assumptions, which then requires $||f||_{L^2}\leq C||f||_{L^4}\leq \infty$ in order to verify  my apriori assumption, or maybe there is another way to bound the $L^2$ norm of $f$.

Comment: The idea of introducing weighted norm might work, I'm trying to modify my energy in some weighted space $L^2(\Omega, w)$, where the weight $w$ is in $L^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Making such functions is easy. For example take $f_n = 1_{[0,1]} + \frac{1}{n} 1_{[1,n]}$.  Then all $L^p$ norms ($p>1+\delta$) are comparable and close to $1$.

Comment: the question does not ask for functions, but for function spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If two Banach spaces are continuously embedded as subspaces of a topological vector space, then their vector sum and their intersection have natural structures of Banach spaces (in the first case as a quotient, in the second case as a closed subspace of their product). Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you can  take the intersection of $L^2$ and $L^4$  (which are subspaces of the space of equivalence classes of meaurable functions) to get a Banach space with the required property.

Comment: $L^2\cap L^4$ does not have the required property: take $f_n=1_{[0,n]}$, you have $||f_n||_2=n^{1/2}$ while $||f_n||_4=n^{1/4}$...